# Каким образом работает IP если адреса не уникальны?

Tags: ip

Я не знаю деталей протоколов Интернет и времени на изучение RFC нет.

Объясните, какая уникальная комбинация идентификаторов используется для доставки пакетов к конкретному терминалу? Ведь IP-адреса всех моих компьютеров одинаковы.

Comment: Добавьте к IP номер порта

Comment: Если адресс у всех одинаковый, то они либо за натом (и мы говорим о адресе роутера), либо они в разных подсетях, либо просто криво настроена сеть (в одной подсети машины с одинаковым айпи очень плохо работают).

Comment: @KoVadim Сервис https://whoer.net/ru показывает одинаковые, а подсетевые разные.

Comment: похоже Вы просто за натом. В данном случае это забота роутера.

Comment: @KoVadim Получается, что на компютер, находящийся за NAT-ом, невозможно доставить призвольный IP пакет. И возможна работа толко по TCP/IP, где и определено понятие порта. И то только как клиента. Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: наполовину. Для того, что бы доставить произвольный пакет "внутрь сети", роутер должен знать некое правило для доставки. Например, в настройках роутера можно сказать, что все пакеты, которые приходят на порт 7777 перенаправлять на 192.168.1.4, а 8989 перенаправлять на 192.168.1.3 порт 3333. Эту фичу поддерживают многие роутеры. Если клиент за натом отправлял пакет  "наружу", то роутер об этом знает и какое то время ждет обратного пакета "назад". На этом построено так называемое "пробиваение ната".

Comment: @KoVadim Спасибо. Ну свой роутер, допустим, я настроить смогу. А роутер провайдера? Пожоже поставить, тихонько, серверок на своем рабочем компьютере не получится.

Comment: Простите у провайдера хотя бы серий айпи (он же динамический).

Comment: @KoVadim Ну, да.

Answer (score 2):

Вы используете сервис https://whoer.net/ru для получения своего ВНЕШЕНГО IP, который принадлежит: либо вашему роутеру к которому подключены несколько компьютеров, либо оборудованию провайдера - которое реализует технологию NAT. В локальной сети, компьютеры для связи используют свои локальные адреса, их этот сервис Вам не покажет, надо использовать инструменты операционной системы. Win: ipconfig, Linux: ip a show

Answer (score 1):

В среде передачи для идентификации адресата, которому следует доставить пакет, выполняется по аппаратному адресу. В сетях Ethernet его роль выполняет МАС-адрес. Если местоположение нужного МАС неизвестно, оборудование выполнит рассылку пакета по всем своим интерфейсам, если известно - только в тот интерфейс, где находится нужный МАС. Исключение - старые свичи, но и современные, если переполнена МАС-таблица, поступают так же. Это что касается отправки.
Что касается приёма - сетевой интерфейс в обычном режиме игнорирует все пакеты, направленные не на его МАС. Исключение - пассивное оборудование (свичи-коммутаторы), и интерфейсы в режиме приёма транзитных пакетов (promiscuous mode). Далее сетевой интерфейс передаст этот пакет на обработку программному обеспечению, который извлечёт из пакета IP, и если "не моё" - опять же проигнорирует, если не спецрежим работы.
Конечно, всё это очень общо и имеет массу исключений, часть из которых упомянута.

Если же под "IP адреса всех моих компьютеров одинаковы" имеется в виду, что они одинаковы для внешнего наблюдателя - т.е. используется NAT,- то тут любой уходящий от них пакет формирует на NAT-роутере сессию, и уже через неё пакеты обратно попадают куда нужно. Сессия идентифицируется набором адрес+порт источника+приёмника - четвёрка чисел, для каждой сессии уникальная (ну и на самом деле ещё протокол). Потому даже для одного компьютера сессии (например, почты и браузера, или получения веб-страницы и получения картинки на ней) не смешиваются.

Comment: В воросе имелись в виду IP адреса. Может быть я не совсем понятно выразился. Но думаю, что ответ не следует давать как для домохозяйки, с расчетом на то, что она все равно ничего не поймет.